# simple usage of .prototype, whats happening behind the scenes?

Tags: javascript

I've been reading a javascript book which just recently started introducing `prototype`. I've also been looking at some other stackoverflow questions on `.prototype` and `__proto__` and they all have some examples that are a bit too advanced for me and i'm having trouble understand them. Now the book is explaining this in a very confusing way so I thought I'd ask here for the basic understanding of it. Heres some code I just made up

```
function Person(firstname,lastname){
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

Person.prototype.getFullName = function(){
    return this.firstname + " " + this.lastname;
}
var john = new Person('John','Doe');
console.log(john);
```

Now heres where my confusion arises. To my understanding, behind the scenes every `function` has a `prototype` but until we use the keyword of `new` it isn't really coming in to play.

To what I can understand or deduce from my book is that `.prototype` here is allowing us to add a method to the `Person` function.

Cool. So If I do `console.log(john.getFullName());`, we get `John Doe`. Nice! Just as suspected. But how come if I do `console.log(john)` it points to the `Person` function and displays `firstname: 'John'`, and `lastname: Doe`.

What happened to the method we just added with `Person.prototype.getFullName`? Why isn't that showing when we log `John`?

Comment: As I understand it it, your code is adding the function to the prototype of Person. If you tried using `console.log(this.prototype)` instead, it should work. Or throw an undefined exception.

Comment: So what if I create another user , var john2 = new Person('John2','Doe');. Is there a way so that I can inherit everything but getFullName? Since If I console.log(john2) it will inherit the getFullName which I just added to proto?

Comment: @cresjoy, there is no way to partially inherit it. When you do 'john2 = new Person('...')', it will inherit everything in 'Person.prototype': nothing more, nothing less. If you want to override 'getFullName', you can always do 'john2.getFullName = function(){ .. do something else .. }'. This works as it will first look in john2 before trying Person.prototype. Although if you do this, you should look into just making a new class/function that inherits Person

Comment: I see. This is indeed some confusing stuff :O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shows up if you expand the `__proto__` dropdown in the console. Because you added the function to the prototype, that's where it shows up.

[image: Function in prototype]

Comment: Oh I see. Can't believe I didn't see that.

Answer (score 0):

Objects in Javascript work by 'prototypal inheritance' where each object has regular properties `firstname`, `lastname` but is also linked to a regular object used as the 'prototype' (specified in the `__proto__` property). The linking process is done automatically when you do `var john = new Person(...)`: by specifying `Person.prototype`, it knows that when you make an instance of Person, it should be linked to `Person.prototype`

When you do `console.log(john)`, it will only show the properties directly in the john object.

But, when you do `john.getFullName()`, Javascript's inheritance model knows that if it doesn't find `getFullName` in the `john` object, it will recursively look for it in `__proto__` until it finds it. So it will use the `getFullName` function in `Person.prototype` because it was linked with that object when `john` was created.

Answer (score 0):

Prototypes are used for inheritance in javascript. Think of it like this: every object (except one) has a prototype. the one that doesn't is at the top of the chain and is the end of the inheritance hierarchy. Every object in that chain gets all of the functions and properties of the one above it. This is done through the prototypes. When you add a function or another variable to an objects prototype, as I understand it, every instance of that object will receive it's own copy of it. The thing about java script is that there are about 6 different ways to create an object -- the new keyword is entirely syntactical sugar -- and each one creates an object. Your book should have said at one point or another that even functions are objects.

Javascript isn't that confusing. It's just powerful and designed differently. Its a week reference system making it robust but also prone to errors due to programmer mistakes.